# Python Homework help: using a range of factorials in an equation (first post ever!)

Tags: python, range, equation, factorial

I need help with some python homework.
I'm looking to solve for e in e= 1+((1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+(1/4!)+(1/5!)+(1/6!)+(1/7!)+(1/8!)+(1/9!)+(1/10!))

We have gone over range, I am now aware of both of the ways to find a factorial, but am having trouble with combining all this and I'm trying to test every step along the way but cannot get over this hump. And I still have to insert it into an equation after as well

```
import math
i=1

math.factorial(i)

(math.factorial(range((int(1,11)))

print (i)

a=1

for i in range(1,11):    #start off with a range from 1-10

    a += 1/i    #a represents each fraction: this is solved first

    print(a)    #this says we want to add the list of fractions together

e = 1 + a    #add 1 to all those fractions' sums

print(e)    #finally, just display what e solves to
```

Comment: According to the instructions, you want `a += 1/factorial(i)`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
The point about rubber-duck debugging is especially relevant: programming isn't a trial-and-error job where you try a million combinations to see what gives you the correct answer -- you need to calmly think about the code you're writing, what that code tells the computer to do, and if that is what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing that along with the other adjustments and got it! @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

You should accumulate the current factorial as you go through the range and use it to build the result:

```
def invfact(e):
    f = 1      # track factorials
    r = 1      # accumulated result
    for n in range(1,e+1):
        f *= n    # current factorial (n!)
        r += 1/f  # add to result
    return r
```